# How to let optional parameter decide sorting of a column

Tags: t-sql

Let's say I have this SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[testsp]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @start datetime,
    @end datetime,
    @sort int = 1
AS
BEGIN
    set nocount on;
    select
        t1.Name,
        sum(t2.sum) as Salary
    from
        persons t1 inner join
        payments t2 on(t1.ID = t2.PersonID)
    where
        t1.Active = 1 and 
        t2.TimeOfTransfer between @start and @end
    group by 
        t1.Name
    order by 
        [Salary] desc
END
```

How do I write my order by to let it sort ascending or descending depending on the value in @sort?

Comment: Just checking - this is for SQL Server, right? What version?

Answer (score 1):

```
...
ORDER
    BY CASE WHEN @sort = 1 THEN Salary END ASC
     , CASE WHEN @sort = 0 THEN Salary END DESC
```

P.S. I would probably change the definition of your `@sort` parameter to either a **bit** (values 0 or 1 only) or **char(4)** (for 'ASC' or 'DESC') `:-)`

Comment: I tried this before, but it only gives me "Invalid column name 'Salary'." :(